# Why don’t conditional types work in generic functions?

Tags: typescript

Why can’t TypeScript use the constraints on the type parameters of a generic function to infer the types of parameters or the return type?

```
function isNum<T extends number>(x:T):T extends number?”Y”:”N”{
    return “Y”; // <- error: type “Y” is not assignable to type ‘T extends number?”Y”:”N”’
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired result (besides forking TS)?

(using TS 2.9.2)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning values where a generic type is expected generally does not work, typescript assumes the value will not be compatible. This is because when we have a generic type that type represents any possible subtype of `T`.

Now in this case it's pretty obvious `T` will always be `"Y"` because there already is a constraint on `T`, but typescript just will not try to deduce this. An even more obvious case will not work, because typescript simply will not do any analysis in this case:

```
function isNum<T extends number>(x: T): T extends number ? "Y" : "Y" {
    return "Y"; // still an error 
}
```

The only solution is to use a type assertion:

```
function isNum<T extends number>(x: T): T extends number ? "Y" : "N" {
    return "Y" as any;
}
```

**Edit**

As noted by @jcalz another very good option is to use multiple overloads (or more specifically a public overload that uses conditional types, and an implementation one that does not use conditional types)

```
function isNum<T extends number>(x: T): T extends number ? "Y" : "N"
function isNum(x: number): "Y" | "N" {
    return "Y";
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a good GitHub issue tracking the pain of assignability for conditional types.  Anyway, usually in these cases I use a single overload where the call signature has the conditional type and the implementation signature has a union instead.  This at least makes it possible to implement.

Comment: Yeah, that is also a good option I will add it, didn't come to mind when I wrote the answer for some reason

Comment: I looked and it seems like [Microsoft/TypeScript#24821](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24821) is intended to deal with this problem, but I don't know when it will make it into the language.

Answer (score 0):

No, Typescript doesn't yet support conditional return types. As for your case, you can do following few things:

### Return type as an Enum

```
enum YesNo {
  Y= 'Y',
  N= 'N'
}
function isNum<T extends Number>(x:T) : YesNo {
  return x as any instanceof Number ? YesNo.Y : YesNo.N;
}
```

### Strict return type

```
function isNum<T extends Number>(x:T) : 'Y' | 'N' {
  return x as any instanceof Number ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

### If you want return type as specific types

```
interface ANumber extends Number {
  ...
}
interface BNumber extends Number {
  ...
}
function isNum<T extends Number>(x:T) : ANumber | BNumber {
  return x;
}
```

Note: Above interfaces can also be classes.